# How to add index from JSX map to CSS file?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-select

I have n dropdown input element which I am re-using in differernt parts of different applications. The dropdown input element has options with dropdowns inside of itself. The dropdowns can vary in length, and have 50 options or just 5. Something like this:

[image]

I need to add some styling based on a class `react-select-2-option-[indexOfTheOptionWithDropdown]`. For example the dynamic css class for `Sydney 333` is `react-select-2-option-2` because it's the second dropdown element in the whole input.
`Sydney 333222` has a dynamic class of `react-select-2-option-1`.

However, I have no idea how to do it in a way that the application would be able to recognize how many options with dropdowns there are and assign an index to each classes ending based on the length and position in the array of options. I need it because the 'react-select' library is assigning default styles which are seemingly impossible to overwrite any other way. I could just hardcode it, although that seems pretty static and anti-codish?

I'm mapping the options in a JSX component with index numbers. And ideally, I'd need to send that index to the CSS file somehow. Is it even possible? Should I use something like styled css components and pass index to overwrite the CSS, or is there some other way to achieve this?

EDIT:
hard coded `react-select-2-option-4:hover` with white background
[image]

default style ( options have a grey background, and do not show that and item is hovered over )
[image]

Comment: Why does each element need its own specific style class?  Can't the same style be applied to all of the elements?

Comment: hey @David I added some more screenshots at the bottom of the post. As you can see the default background is grey. The style class comes from the library. I tried to style both the ID and the class, however only the ID allows to manipulate the background color. So in the end, I believe I have no choice but to either hard code all the possible indexes react-select-2-option-1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13 and so on.. or make it dynamic with an index of the element.

The gray comes from a div container which allows to change the ooptions without dropdowns, but the style affects applies to options

Comment: I have a :hover property on the options element from the left side of the dropdown, but when user hovers over the option with more options.. the gray background is automatically being added to the dropdown options

Comment: by default it works fine, but my client asked for keyboard arrows functionality.. and the :hover style does not apply when choosing options with arrows, so I had to write some functions that would detect if an option is selected with arrows.. but that caused the options of options to be grey as well

Answer (score 1):

You can use an index to define a CSS class name like the one below.

```
var options = <list of DOM options like Sydney 333222 and Sydney 333>;
for (var i in options) {
  options[i].className = `react-select-2-option-${i}`;
}
```

But this is a strange approach. It's better for you to use a variable with common CSS and apply this to the specific style:

```
var commonCss = { color: 'red', fontWeight: 'bold' };
var especificCss = [{ border: 'solid 1px blue'}];
var options = <list of DOM options like Sydney 333222 and Sydney 333>;
for (var i in options) {
  Object.keys({ ...commonCss, ...especificCss[i]}).forEach(function(key) {
    options[i][key].className = options[key];
  });
}
```

Also you can to define a class css with the common style and them apply only the specific.

```
var especificCss = [{ border: 'solid 1px blue'}];
var options = <list of DOM options like Sydney 333222 and Sydney 333>;
for (var i in options) {
  Object.keys(especificCss[i]).forEach(function(key) {
    options[i][key].className = options[key];
  });
}
```